# CSS - are calls to a server being made when it's inside a div that has display:none?

Tags: php, html, css

I have two blocks of code that are managed wether they are being shown on a screen with CSS using `display:none` On 2 different style sheets.

Now my question is if the page is loaded in the browser and this is detected will that still load the code inside the div and just be hidden or will it be skipped like what happens to a comment?

Comment: Try it and see what happens.

Comment: I am sorry to say that this reflects gross misunderstanding of the HTTP protocol on your side... HTML structure is downloaded *in full* inside the body. The only two ways content may be further loaded at a different stage is when: the content is a reference/link (eg: script tags, img tags...) OR when the content is being loaded and injected via javascript+ajax.

Comment: Cool thanks @Christian You answer makes sense and yup I accept the knowledge is lacking within this term - hence the question:-)

Comment: When I have some HTML I want to use later but don't want rendered, I put it in `<script>` tag with a bogus `type`. For example `<script type="text/my-html-template" id="foo"><p>foobar</p></script>`. Then later on I can access the HTML using `$('foo').innerHTML`. The browser won't know what scripting language "text/my-html-template" is, and so will completely ignore it. But it's still in the DOM tree.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In short, yes. The browser will always load the dom in full before loading the css, so your DOM elements will have already been loaded, and any assets (e.g. video or images) will have begun loading (and will continue to do so), before the browser reaches the CSS telling it not to display the element.

The below diagram shows the order the browser takes:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your answer and the diagram helps too:-)

Comment: I think most browsers don't follow that workflow. For example AFAIK all browsers actually parse the HTML twice now. Once without executing javascript and then a second time with javascript enabled. Only the second parse is actually rendered, but the first parse is used to predict what the outcome of the second, improving performance by downloading files before it knows exactly what will need to be downloaded.

Comment: Very interesting. Do you have a link with detail?

Answer (score 1):

1st, your browser will load ALL your HTML when the page loads. The only way I know to prevent it is to put your HTML inside of a server side languages "if" statement. (or something similar server side)

Example:

```
<?php
   if($variable == "Something"){ ?>
      <p>I want this to load.</p>
   <?php }
   else if($variable == "Something Else"){ ?>
      <p>This should load instead.</p>
   <?php }
?>
```

But, if you need the hidden HTML to show/hide based on something using javascrip or css hover, etc, this wont work because this script is executed on the server and **ONLY** shows what's inside the TRUE if statement.

You could probably use javascript for this as well. (I'm not a javascript genius, but I'm sure it's doable.)

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want the content to load in the code than you could just put the content in a cache using Javascript easily. Although by itself the content will load in the code. If you need assistance on creating a data cache with JS I can help you out.

Comment: How is this slightly related to what he is asking?

Comment: "if the page is loaded in the browser and this is detected will that still load the code inside the div and just be hidden or will it be skipped like what happens to a comment?" He is wondering whether or not it will view the display:none as a comment in a way. What I'm saying is that it will not show up as a comment, it will be in the code. But if you were to add it to a cache data with JS than the code would not show up in the default HTML version, it would be hidden. As it would be on a server-sided file. Almost like making a php file, because you can't access the code of a php file.

Comment: He's asking for a ball and you gave him a ballpen.

Comment: I don't think you really understand what you are talking about Christian. I just gave him the complete answer to his question.

Comment: Funny your answer completely contradicts my comment above...code is loaded directly, regardless whether a containing div is visible or not. And frankly, I have now idea how we ended up discussing caching (or storing html in a js variable) for the matter.

Comment: "Although by itself the content will load in the code." directly from my answer. And as I said in my post if he wanted assitance on hiding the code from public than I could help him but I answered his question that the code will show up with it is hidden using CSS or not. I only edited it once right after I posted it, it even shows that. I put "If you want" when I meant to say "If you don't want".